# Design concept for dynamic database project

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

As part of a bigger project, I wish to build an app which allows users to create tables. The user should be able to add tables, add column categories/groups and add data dynamicly (and of course edit and delete).

What would be the best way of attacking this? I would think that a new database table should be built as per on the UI, but what happens if the user ends up with 2000 columns? And what about the grouping of columns?

I am thinking that the best way is to have a max columns per database table after which it joins tables for the UI. And also another table for column categories. What are your thoughts on this? Is there a better way of handling large amount of dynamic data on the fly?

Thanks

Comment: Let users create tables?! Are you sure all these 'users' know about basic principles of RDBMS with a grasp of PK, FK etc. If not, then creating tables and running queries off of it would degrade your system for sure. Tables should always be created by developers of an application. Let the users just add rows to predefined set of tables. Create as many tables as your users need, but do it yourself/or get the dev team to do it.

Comment: The data wont be relational as it's not being used for development. Its simply a static table of data. Graphs may be produced from the tables. So users can upload / insert their data and then generate simple bars graphs from it.

Answer (score 0):

Well since your are trying to create such a project, it already exist such a project, and a very good one:

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Comment: No, I'm sorry - that is not what I am trying to do. I use PHPmyadmin all the time. Bassicly I am trying to build a spreadsheet and save it to a database. And that is what the user needs to do (not the developer like phpmyadmin)

Comment: Oow ok! I undestand now. It should be in your question.